# Zoom , pan inside a rectangle bound

Tags: actionscript-3, zooming

I am building a site with some features of google map. I want to pan, zoom in out a map with tweening effect. But when I zoom the map(Movie clip) it zooms out of the rectangular boundary.
I also want to wrap the map(when scrolled).
How can I do all these?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the panning/zooming example from the Flex Interface guide:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/samples/fig_panzoom/

It demonstrates how to do what you're looking for (though not the map wrapping).

Answer (score 0):

To wrap, you will need multiple copies of your map image.